# What can i do with RaisePropertyChanged?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, propertychanged

I'm using MVVM Light in a Windows Phone Silverlight application.

I don't really get how RaisePropertyChanged should works; Let me explain, in code like this

```
private Recipe _selectedRecipe;

public Recipe SelectedRecipe
{
    get
    {
        return this._selectedRecipe;
    }
    set
    {
        this._selectedRecipe = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRecipe");
    }
}
```

What should happen when RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRecipe") is called?

I expect the call to a new method with my code to execute, or something like that, but i can't be able to find something similar in (the few) examples i found. So, how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InotifyPropertyChanged` event is important for data binding in Silverlight, and the `RaisePropertyChanged` method provided as part of the MVVM-Light toolkit is a helper to raise the event if anyone is listening out for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can i implement a listener for these events?

Comment: When you use `{Binding SelectedRecipe}` - here is your listener is implemented for `SelectedRecipe` property changes by Silverlight himself

Comment: Ok but where can i write my code to execute when RaisePropertyChanged() is called?

Comment: Oh God. I'm dumb. RaisePropertyChanged() only serves to update the binded elements in the view? O_O